# I have one jsp. I am trying to hide menu item in jsp based on user login

Tags: java, jsp

I am trying to hide menu item in jsp based on `user.getUsrInd()`

```
<div class="dropdown">
                        <li class="dropbtn">Perofrmance</li>
                        <div class="dropdown-content">

                            <a href="team.jsp">My Performance</a> 

                            <%if(user.getUsrInd()=="S") %>
                              <a href="team.jsp">Rate</a>  

                        </div>
                    </div>
```

but whatever may be the user_ind the menu item is getting hided, even if value is S

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change if to:

```
if("S".equals(user.getUsrInd()))
```

Comment: what is the difference?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/767372/java-string-equals-versus

Comment: hey thats working fine now. i'll check that. thank you :)

Comment: sure , waiting for that :)